# Ajax functionality Query

Tags: ajax, asp.net-ajax

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function loadXMLDoc()
{
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","ajax_info.txt",true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="myDiv"><h2>Let AJAX change this text</h2></div>
<button type="button" onclick="loadXMLDoc()">Change Content</button>

</body>
</html>
```

This is the soimple example of changing text using Ajax up on a button click. Here, we are using xmlhttp.responseText property and assigning it to a DIV before opening the document itself??How is it possible?Please explain in detail? Sorry to be Dumb...I'm learning ajax now...

Comment: What `document` are you taking about?

Comment: I meant by xmlhttp.open method. Here we reading data from ajax_info.txt.